# Footer's size not relative to its content. (HTML, CSS)

Tags: html, css

I need footer to have size relative to its contents, so if text/images in it take up more space on smaller devices, the footer will adapt and get higher.

```
body footer{
 height: auto;
 background-color: #333333;
 max-width: 800px;
 padding: 15px;
}
```

This is how it looks when using css above:

[image: Image of the footer]

I used abosulte size before but it obviously didn't work well on smaller devices with text taking up more space in height. How can I make height of the footer adapt to its contents?

Comment: instead of using 'px' in width, you can try using '%' in it and it will automatically adapt the sizes to any devices

Comment: Try not to give exact height to your components at above